# Soundproofing or sound insulation? What is the difference?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I would like to understand what the difference is between *soundproofing* and *sound insulation*?

Which word would you use in this sentence?

'The *soundproofing*/*sound insulation* could be better in the room. I could hear every single word behind the walls.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a matter of degree - sound-proofing (technically at least) prevents any transmission of sound, whereas insulation merely reduces noise levels.

In your example, either could be used, but 'sound proofing' would probably be used more often, even though that detracts a little from my definitions!